# calculate the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} (1+3 \sin \frac{1}{x})^{[x]}$

Tags: real-analysis

I know that $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} (1+3 \sin \frac{1}{x})^{x}=e^{3}$ but if instead of $x$ I have the integer part of $x$ i.e., $[x]$, is it the same?

Comment: Try using the inequality $x - 1 \le [x] \le x$ and Sandwich Theorem.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem

Comment: For $x > 2$, you can write $$\left(1+3 \sin \frac{1}{x}\right)^{x-1} \le \left(1+3 \sin \frac{1}{x}\right)^{[x]} \le \left(1+3 \sin \frac{1}{x}\right)^{x}.$$ Both the left and right sides have the same limit as $x \to +\infty$. Can you conclude about the middle limit?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani just want to say that I love the name Sandwich Theorem so much more than Squeeze Theorem. I'm going to start using that

Comment: the inequality is right for $x>2$ because $x \rightarrow +\infty?$

Comment: @GiuliaB.: Not exactly. For $r > 1$ and $a \le b$, we have $r^a \le r^b$. I have used that $x > 2$ implies that $1 + 3\sin(1/x) > 1$. I can then use Sandwich (Squeeze) theorem because for using it in the case $x \to \infty$ we need the inequality to be true for $x > M$ for some fixed $M \in \Bbb R$. (In this case, $M = 2$.)

Comment: @doobdood: oh, that's funny because I was taught it as Sandwich theorem and I always found the name "Squeeze" rather amusing.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating from the comments.

For $x > 2$, we have $\dfrac1x < \dfrac12$ and thus, $1 + 3\sin\dfrac{1}{x} > 1$.

Moreover, for $x > 2$, we also have $x - 1 \le [x] \le x$. (This is true for all $x \in \Bbb R$, in fact.)

Thus, we get that

$$\left(1 + 3\sin\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{x-1} \le \left(1 + 3\sin\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{[x]} \le \left(1 + 3\sin\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{x}. (*)$$

---

Moreover, note that
\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(1 + 3\sin\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{x-1}\\
= &\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(1 + 3\sin\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{x}\cdot\left(1 + 3\sin\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{-1}\\
=& e^3\cdot1 \\
=& e^3.
\end{align}

---

Thus, the left and right end of $(*)$ have the same limit as $x\to+\infty$.

Now, to use [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) for the case $x \to +\infty$, we need the inequality $(*)$ to be true on some interval of the form $(a, +\infty)$. In this case, we have $a = 2$ and thus, we see that

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(1 + 3\sin\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{[x]} = e^3.$$